# Best practice for creating an invitation link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on a rails app that allows a user to send an event invitation to another user in the system. The recipient of the invitation will have the option to accept or reject the invitation (sort of like e-vite i suppose).

My plan is to create a resource that handles accepting and rejecting the invitation. I'll have the user log-in first if need be and then do a "friendly forward" to the accept/reject page. The thing that is special here is that I only want one person to be able to accept an invitation. Then all other people after that will get a "event already accepted" message. I'm concerned about two things that i'm looking for advice on how to handle:

1.) race condition:

How do I handle two people accepting the same event at (nearly) the same time? Is there a way to help prevent this to ensure that only one person can claim "ownership" of the event.

2.) security

Is there anything I should do to make sure that people don't spoof the accept link and start putting unwanted rows into my DB in the event/invitation model?

Just for context, the "invitation" will be for babysitting, so I really only want one person accepting the invitation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) Race conditions:
The state of the invitation (accepted, rejected or not yet responded) could be stored as an integer value in your database table.  The DB infrastructure should handle race conditions.

(2) Security:
Don't provide users with a way to CREATE a new row in the database, and put a conditional in your Ruby code checking the state of the database that will allow the Users to UPDATE the database only when the invitation has a certain state.